# Spring Data Jpa with Sybase - UnimplementedOperationException

Tags: jpa, spring-data, sybase

I'm seeing an issue with persisting objects to Sybase suing Spring Data JPA. The error I see is

```
com.sybase.jdbc3.utils.UnimplementedOperationException: 
The method com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybConnection.prepareStatement(String, int) 
has not been completed and should not be called.
```

I've simplified this down to an entity object with and id and a description and still see the error.

My entity class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_bsc_region")
public class Region implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7985499571755472582L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "bsc_region_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "region_name")
private String regionName;

protected Region() {
    // for JPA only
}

public Region(final String regionName) {
    this.regionName = regionName;
}

/**
 * Accessor method for id.
 *
 * @return value of id
 */
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

/**
 * Modifier method for id.
 *
 * @param id
 *            the id to set
 */
public void setId(final Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * Accessor method for regionName.
 *
 * @return value of regionName
 */
public String getRegionName() {
    return this.regionName;
}

/**
 * Modifier method for regionName.
 *
 * @param regionName
 *            the regionName to set
 */
    public void setRegionName(final String regionName) {
        this.regionName = regionName;
    }
}
```

My test is

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/spring/application-test.xml")
public class RegionIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    RegionRepository repo;

    /**
     * Test save with only Generic Info details
     */
    @Test
    public void testSave() throws Exception {
        final Region region = new Region("CG Region");

        this.repo.save(region);
    }
}
```

My data source

```
<bean id="bscDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sybase:Tds:DUKMACA09.SYSTEMS.UK.CO:10010/bsc" />
        <property name="username" value="obscuredusername" />
        <property name="password" value="obscuredpwd" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    </bean>
```

and my entity manager factory is set up as

```
<bean id="bscEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="bscDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.bsc.model"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="bscPersistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseASE15Dialect"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
                </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and my jconn version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jconn3</groupId>
    <artifactId>jconn3</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I cant see what the issue is

The full console output from the test is

```
2016-10-11 18:49:19,636 DEBUG [main] support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'save' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2016-10-11 18:49:19,640 DEBUG [main] support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2016-10-11 18:49:19,642 DEBUG [main] jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@2c5d529e] for JPA transaction
2016-10-11 18:49:19,783 DEBUG [main] jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@5e13fb15]
2016-10-11 18:49:28,642 DEBUG [main] spi.SqlStatementLogger - insert into tbl_bsc_region (region_name) values (?)
select @@identity
Hibernate: insert into tbl_bsc_region (region_name) values (?)
select @@identity
2016-10-11 18:49:28,650 DEBUG [main] support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
2016-10-11 18:49:28,652 DEBUG [main] jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@2c5d529e]
2016-10-11 18:49:28,749 DEBUG [main] jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@2c5d529e] after transaction
2016-10-11 18:49:28,750 DEBUG [main] jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
2016-10-11 18:49:28,896 DEBUG [main] support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test method: context [[TestContext@a98ce7e testClass = RegionIntegrationTest, testInstance = com.bsc.repository.RegionIntegrationTest@361cb7a1, testMethod = testSave@RegionIntegrationTest, testException = com.sybase.jdbc3.utils.UnimplementedOperationException: The method com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybConnection.prepareStatement(String, int) has not been completed and should not be called., mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@175bc6c8 testClass = RegionIntegrationTest, locations = '{classpath:/spring/application-test.xml}', classes = '{}', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader']]], class dirties context [false], class mode [null], method dirties context [false].
2016-10-11 18:49:28,905 DEBUG [main] support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [[TestContext@a98ce7e testClass = RegionIntegrationTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@175bc6c8 testClass = RegionIntegrationTest, locations = '{classpath:/spring/application-test.xml}', classes = '{}', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader']]], dirtiesContext [false].
2016-10-11 18:49:28,930 INFO [Thread-2] jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'bscPersistenceUnit'
```

When debugging I see the error occur in the Spring class

org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor

in the method below where it calls

return invocation.proceed();

```
@Override
public Object invoke(final MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    // Work out the target class: may be {@code null}.
    // The TransactionAttributeSource should be passed the target class
    // as well as the method, which may be from an interface.
    Class<?> targetClass = (invocation.getThis() != null ? AopUtils.getTargetClass(invocation.getThis()) : null);

    // Adapt to TransactionAspectSupport's invokeWithinTransaction...
    return invokeWithinTransaction(invocation.getMethod(), targetClass, new InvocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public Object proceedWithInvocation() throws Throwable {
            return invocation.proceed();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: so who calls it, if it shouldn't be called ? That is what a stack trace is for ...

Comment: It's called as part of the spring data repository implementation on the save method. I suspect the error may be misleading but even trying to debug the spring source code I can't figure it out.

Comment: so why not post it in your question and others can judge also? Called by Spring?, called by Hibernate? called by something else?

Comment: Not interested in what you call. Interested in the STACK TRACE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the JTDS driver:

```
<groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
<artifactId>jtds</artifactId> 
<version>1.2.8</version>
```

Jconn3 has a problem with identity cols

Comment: Thanks Martin that has resolved the issue. Genuinely helpful response (and no CAPSLOCK!!) Cheers